# Making a file as default stdin

Tags: python, default, stdin

I want to take input from a file by default.
For example:

```
num=input()
```

This statement should take input from a file instead of waiting for key hits. I do not want to do it by redirecting standard input to a file, I want it by default. Simply, keyboard is default device for input, so instead of keyboard I want a file to give input.

Comment: `input` is, by definition, for reading from standard input. If you don't want to connect your file to standard input, you don't want to use `input`. Try the `fileinput`  module.

Comment: You can't use `input` to read in a file.

Comment: If you don't want to use the `fileinput` module for some reason, try reassigning it manually with a `sys.stdin = open("path to file")` then afterwards the `input()` function will read characters from that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach your file to the standard input on the OS level like this:

```
python script.py <input.txt
```

To the script, it will seem like whenever `input()` is invoked, the user types the next line from the file.

Comment: actually i am running python script from java. if i am running without redirecting input from a file its working fine:                                    
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "python add.py");                                       but as i am using the method you suggested its not working.                  
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "python add.py < input.txt");   
its getting paused not nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround.

```
def file_input(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
_input_iterator = file_input('input.txt')

def input_():               # replace input
    return _input_iterator.next()
```

You may avoid the global variable by wrapping it with class or make it a module.

---

I don't like this but it is possible. To really replace the stdin (haven't tryied it on windows)

```
import sys
sys.stdin = file('input.txt', 'r')
input_line = input()
```

For UNIX model, `stdin` is just a file. When you use utilities like `pipe` you would modify/redirect `stdin` of child processes. It feels more comfortable if `stdin` of a process is modified in parent's scope (e.g. a terminal). Otherwise it doesn't seem like 'std' anymore.

Comment: Suggest that you (and the OP) take a look at the `fileinput` [documention](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput).

Comment: `fileinput` is more reasonable indeed! Maybe the asker is stuck with global name `input`.